# Eclipse error : Your project contains error(s) , please them before running your application in android

Tags: android

When i run my project , I get " Your project contains error(s) , please them before running your application" this error . I searched this error on Google , There i got a lot of solutions all these did not work for me . I cleaned and Build my project , Restart my eclipse , in .android deleted debug.keystore and clean and build my project , But did not work for me . Please help me .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you checked what errors your project contains?

Comment: May be you are missing some libraries which your project requires.
Try whether there are errors in the layouts(xml).

Comment: No error showing in my project

Comment: @ManojKumar I doubt that there are no errors. check the "Problems" tab and see if there are any errors there. If there were no errors, then Eclipse wouldn't complain.

Comment: @Panini I already checked , in "problems " there are no error

Comment: Can you see your R Class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow My steps :

There are many possiblity of this type of error try by one of the following .

**Step 1** Right Click on your app then check library and order and export tab there may
   be any error remove that according to your project .

**Step 2**  Right Click on your app then go to java compiler and made change of 
   compiler level

**Step 3** If you have added any library project check that also

It works for me hope it will work for you also .

Comment: to be honest I don't understand why to "Right Click on my app" but you got me οn the right track to fix my same problem. Was a missing lib/jar on build path (under: right click your project>build path>configure build path..>check "libraries" as well as "order and export" tab and maybe re-add your missing Jar(marked with that common red error sign). So thanks! +1 for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all the solutions you generally come across in the Net turned out inappropriate.

What I have recently found is that if you wanted to import a given Android project,

and you used General/Existing Projects into Workspace or Archive File,

you may probably face the issue above when there is no problem in the source itself.

What I did was using [Existing Android Code Into Workspace] instead of the above.

With this authentic way of importing Android project, such an error did not come about.

//

Of course, this applies when you properly added some necessary libraries and you have

no issue with your source codes.